# How to pass array in kernel, do something and then return it - OpenCL

Tags: c++, opencl

I am trying to pass an array to OpenCL kernel, then do something with it and pass it back to host. I have modified code in this [tutorial](http://www.fixstars.com/en/opencl/book/OpenCLProgrammingBook/first-opencl-program/).

This is just kernel for figuring out how OpenCL actually works. I hope that this would just substract 2 from the first element of array1 and store it into the first element of array2:

```
__kernel void test(global int* array1, global int* array2) {
    array2[0] = array1[0] - 2;
}
```

In main I have two arrays, one (host1) with some numbers and the second (host2) initialized to zeros.
Than to create memory buffers I use:

```
memobj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, MEM_SIZE * sizeof(int), &host1, &ret);
memobj2 = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, MEM_SIZE * sizeof(int), &host2, &ret);
```

After building program I set arguments:

```
ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &host1);
ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &host2);
```

And then after execution I try to get that array back.

```
ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, memobj2, CL_TRUE, 0, MEM_SIZE * sizeof(int), host2, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Here if I change memobj2 to memobj the host2 will contain values of host1, otherwise it stays the same. I guess that this is not how one will return arrays.

I am stuck at this point.

Comment: How do you execute the kernel? You should give it a local and global work size of 1x1x1. Also: Do you check *every single* return value against errors?

Comment: @leemes Like in tutorial `ret = clEnqueueTask(command_queue, kernel, 0, NULL,NULL);`

Comment: Ok that's actually equivalent to `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` with a range of 1x1x1 I was talking about. Now about the errors, do you check them all?

Comment: @leemes What errors do you mean? Program compiles and runs without erors. I only insert breakpoint after reading buffer. First value in host1 is 200, so in host 2 should be 198. In the end values in host1 and host2 arrays are the same as in the begining.

Comment: Every `cl*` function returns an error code (or almost every). You should check this error. Your tutorial doesn't, and that's bad. You could add something like [**this**](http://tom.scogland.com/blog/2013/03/29/opencl-errors/) to your project and wrap every cl call in some function `void check(cl_int e) { if (e) { throw std::runtime_error(get_error_string(e)); } }` or similar; so all your calls look like `check(clCreateBuffer(...));`

Comment: Ok, that was usefull. At `clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);`says -42 = CL_INVALID_BINARY.

Comment: I guess it's `__global`, not `global`

Comment: @leemes No, it doesn't make a difference. But there was an awkward moment when I found / after last }. Thank you for pointing out those cl errors! I'll keep my eye on that.

Comment: Glad I could help so far. Does it work now or is there still something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your calls to `clSetKernelArg()` are invalid - you should be passing the OpenCL buffer, not the host pointer. For example:

```
ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &memobj);
ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &memobj2);
```

As was already pointed out, you should check the return codes from every OpenCL runtime API call. This would point you towards the error pretty quickly.